# Game Center Matchmaking on OS X Yosemite Not Working

Tags: ios, macos, gamekit

I'm trying to get my game's multiplayer to work on OS X Yosemite. Multiplayer works perfectly on iOS, but on OS X I have encountered many problems.

Before I discuss the issue, let me first explain my setup. I have my OS X app setup in iTunes connect with game center enabled and the multiplayer compatibility is setup correctly as well. I have Game Center enabled in the Xcode project and the appropriate entitlements. I'm using two macs to test. Both are logged in to unique game center accounts and sandbox is enabled.

When I run the app, the local player gets successful authenticated on both macs. However when I try searching for a match, no players are ever found.

Is game center multiplayer matchmaking not working on Yosemite? Once again, my iOS app works fine on sandbox servers, it's just the OS X app that isn't working.

This is serious because I currently can't test my multiplayer game at all on OS X until this is resolved. Has anyone had success getting multiplayer working on Yosemite?

Edit: 
I also have multiplayer compatibility set so that iOS users can play with OS X users. But the matchmaking still won't find players when I search using one mac and one iOS device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the "com.apple.security.network.server" entitlement was missing. It turns out that when you enable the Game Center capability in the new Xcode, only the "com.apple.security.network.client" entitlment is added by default, you still need to manually add the "com.apple.security.network.server" entitlement!

[image]